# file upload progress

Tags: c#, asp.net, file, file-upload

i need to implement the file upload progress in my web page
i have five file upload controls in my page and i want to show the upload progress for each file upload separately.
i there any way to do this.

Thanks
Muthuraman.

Answer (score 4):

This is my project so you can use it http://managemedia.codeplex.com/

Without any flash or silverlight similar facebook and gmail.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ajaxupload](http://ajaxuploader.com/) or consult Matt Berseth's [article](http://mattberseth.com/blog/2008/07/aspnet_file_upload_with_realti_1.html)]

PS:- I don't know if ajaxupload is free or paid

Answer (score 0):

I have tried all of them, [this one](http://darrenjohnstone.net/2008/07/15/aspnet-file-upload-module-version-2-beta-1/) has turned out to be best. Very easily integrates. No deployment issues.

[alt text http://darrenjohnstone.net/wp-content/uploads/2008/07/uploadsmall.png](http://darrenjohnstone.net/2008/07/15/aspnet-file-upload-module-version-2-beta-1/)

[alt text http://darrenjohnstone.net/wp-content/uploads/2008/07/uploadcontrol.png](http://darrenjohnstone.net/2008/07/15/aspnet-file-upload-module-version-2-beta-1/)

**http://darrenjohnstone.net/2008/07/15/aspnet-file-upload-module-version-2-beta-1/**

Comment: The site does not seems to be accessible anymore.

Comment: But you can get the demo from Matt Berseth using it.